# How to use randomly generated number in switch statement?

Tags: c++, random, switch-statement, ctime

i am making a simple program that displays the behaviour of the person from the sentences that i write in switch statement cases. I want to randomly generate a number between 1 and 10 and use it in "switch(*this place*)". So far, i have written the following code and stuck here..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int rand_range(int low, int high)
{
  return rand()%(high-low) + low;
}
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    cout<<"Hi!, this program tells you about your behaviour"<<endl;
    cout<<"press enter to continue";
    cin.get();

    switch(    )
    {
    case 1:
        {
            cout<<"you are rude !";
        }
    case 2:
        {
            cout<<"you are smart";
        }
    case 3:
        {
            cout<<"you try to prove yourself special all the time";
        }
    case 4:
        {
            cout<<"you are good in sarcasm";
        }
    case 5:
        {
            cout<<"you look dumb, but deep inside you are intelligent";
        }
    case 6:
        {
            cout<<"you are always ready for a debate with someone";
        }
    case 7:
        {
            cout<<"you are very lazy";
        }
    case 8:
        {
            cout<<"you are dumber than what you look";
        }
    case 9:
        {
            cout<<"you always try to help others";
        }
    case 10:
        {
            cout<<"you have good decision making capabilities";
        }
    default:
        {
            cout<<"something wrong";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your switch statement in the parentheses you want `(rand() % 10) + 1`. After you have seeded the random number generator the `rand()` function will return a number between 0 and `RAND_MAX`. `RAND_MAX` is a large number.

To get a random number in a range a standard trick is to use the `%` operator. `rand() % 10` returns a number between 0 and 9 inclusive. Add 1 to get your range of 1 through 10.

Comment: thank you ! but now my switch statement is **falling through**.

Comment: @PrakharShukla: You need to append a break; at the end of each of your cases.